# Number of possible equations of K numbers whose sum is N in ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, logic

I have to create a program in ruby on rails so that it will take less time to solve the particular condition. Now i am to getting the less response time for k=4 but response time is more in case of k>5

Problem:

> Problem is response time.
>
> When value of k is more than 5 (k>5) response time is too late for given below equation.

Input: K, N (where 0 < N < ∞, 0 < K < ∞, and K <= N)
Output: Number of possible equations of K numbers whose sum is N.

```
Example Input:
N=10 K=3
Example Output:
Total unique equations = 8
  1 + 1 + 8 = 10
  1 + 2 + 7 = 10
  1 + 3 + 6 = 10
  1 + 4 + 5 = 10
  2 + 2 + 6 = 10
  2 + 3 + 5 = 10
  2 + 4 + 4 = 10
  3 + 3 + 4 = 10
For reference, N=100, K=3 should have a result of 833 unique sets
```

Here is my ruby code

```
module Combination
  module Pairs
    class Equation
      def initialize(params)
        @arr=[]
        @n = params[:n]
        @k = params[:k]
      end

      #To create possible equations
      def create_equations
        return "Please Enter value of n and k" if @k.blank? && @n.blank?
        begin
          Integer(@k)
        rescue
          return "Error: Please enter any +ve integer value of k"
        end
        begin
          Integer(@n)
        rescue
          return "Error: Please enter any +ve integer value of n"
        end
        return "Please enter k < n" if @n < @k
        create_equations_sum
      end

      def create_equations_sum
        aar = []
        @arr = []
        @list_elements=(1..@n).to_a
        (1..@k-1).each do |i|
          aar << [*0..@n-1]
        end
        traverse([], aar, 0)
        return @arr.uniq #return result
      end

      #To check sum
      def generate_sum(*args)
        new_elements = []
        total= 0
        args.flatten.each do |arg|
          total += @list_elements[arg]
          new_elements << @list_elements[arg]
        end
        if total < @n
          new_elements << @n - total
          @arr << new_elements.sort
        else
          return
        end
      end

      def innerloop(arrayOfCurrentValues)
        generate_sum(arrayOfCurrentValues)
      end

      #Recursive method to create dynamic nested loops.
      def traverse(accumulated,params, index) 
        if (index==params.size)
          return innerloop(accumulated) 
        end
        currentParam = params[index]
        currentParam.each do |currentElementOfCurrentParam|
          traverse(accumulated+[currentElementOfCurrentParam],params, index+1)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

run the code using

```
params = {:n =>100, :k =>4}
c = Combination::Pairs::Equation.new(params)
c.create_equations
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Input: K, N (where 0 < N < ∞, 0 < K < ∞, and K <= N) 
Output: Number of possible equations of K numbers whose sum is N.

i have to create a program to match this condition in ruby.
I tried but it fails for k=5

Comment: Please edit your original question and add this question to it. Also maybe add some of your thoughts why it should run correctly, or where your exact problem is.

Comment: please check if it is understandable.

Comment: Have an upvote, no idea why this was downvoted; calculating combinatorial coefficients is an interesting and not entirely trivial task to do efficiently.

Comment: @GBach, notice that there are also three votes to close the question.  Tarun, to avoid having the question closed, I suggest you edit it (ASAP) to clarify what you want (rather than trying to explain in comments).  It seems to me that you are asking for suggestions for a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Tarun, @Uri has posted a solution which I prefer to my own.  If you wish to change your preferred answer selection, you should not be concerned that I will be offended or disappointed.  I hope you will still find value in the explanations I provide for some of the operations.

Comment: hmm. i can understand, but explanation is good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways to compute your answer.  The first is simple but not very efficient; the second, which relies on an optimization technique, is much faster, but requires considerably more code.

**Compact but Inefficient**

This is a compact way to do the calculation, making use of the method [Array#repeated_combination](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-repeated_combination):

*Code*

```
def combos(n,k)
    [*(1..n-k+1)].repeated_combination(3).select { |a| a.reduce(:+) == n }
end
```

*Examples*

```
combos(10,3)
  #=> [[1, 1, 8], [1, 2, 7], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5],
  #    [2, 2, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 4], [3, 3, 4]]

combos(100,4).size
  #=> 832

combos(1000,3).size
  #=> 83333
```

*Comment*

The first two calculations take well under one second, but the third took a couple of minutes.

**More efficient, but increased complexity**

*Code*

```
def combos(n,k)
  return nil   if k.zero?
  return [n]   if k==1
  return [1]*k if k==n
  h = (1..k-1).each_with_object({}) { |i,h| h[i]=[[1]*i] }
  (2..n-k+1).each do |i|
    g = (1..[n/i,k].min).each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) do |m,f|
      im = [i]*m
      mxi = m*i
      if m==k
        f[mxi].concat(im) if mxi==n
      else
        f[mxi] << im if mxi + (k-m)*(i+1) <= n
        (1..[(i-1)*(k-m), n-mxi].min).each do |j|
          h[j].each do |a|
            f[mxi+j].concat([a+im]) if
              ((a.size==k-m && mxi+j==n) ||
               (a.size<k-m && (mxi+j+(k-m-a.size)*(i+1))<=n))
          end
        end
      end  
    end
    g.update({ n=>[[i]*k] }) if i*k == n
    h.update(g) { |k,ov,nv| ov+nv }
  end  
  h[n]
end
```

*Examples*

```
p combos(10,3)
  #=> [[3, 3, 4], [2, 4, 4], [2, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5],
  #    [2, 2, 6], [1, 3, 6], [1, 2, 7], [1, 1, 8]]
p combos(10,4)
  #=> [[2, 2, 3, 3], [1, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 4, 4], 
  #    [1, 2, 2, 5], [1, 1, 3, 5], [1, 1, 2, 6], [1, 1, 1, 7]]
puts "size=#{combos(100 ,3).size}"  #=>   833
puts "size=#{combos(100 ,5).size}"  #=> 38224
puts "size=#{combos(1000,3).size}"  #=> 83333
```

*Comment*

The calculation `combos(1000,3).size` took about five seconds, the others were all well under one second.

*Explanation*

This method employs [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to compute a solution.  The state variable is the largest positive integer used to compute arrays with sizes no more than `k` whose elements sum to no more than `n`.  Begin with the largest integer equal to one. The next step is compute all combinations of `k` or fewer elements that include the numbers 1 and 2, then 1, 2 and 3, and so on, until we have all combinations of `k` or fewer elements that include the numbers 1 through `n`.  We then select all combinations of `k` elements that sum to `n` from the last calculation.

Suppose

```
k => 3
n => 7
```

then

```
h = (1..k-1).each_with_object({}) { |i,h| h[i]=[[1]*i] }
  #=> (1..2).each_with_object({})   { |i,h| h[i]=[[1]*i] }
  #=> { 1=>[[1]], 2=>[[1,1]] }
```

This reads, using the only the number `1`, `[[1]]` is the array of all arrays that sum to `1` and `[[1,1]]` is the array of all arrays that sum to `2`.

Notice that this does not include the element `3=>[[1,1,1]]`.  That's because, already having `k=3` elments, if cannot be combined with any other elements, and sums to `3 < 7`.

We next execute:

```
enum = (2..n-k+1).each #=> #<Enumerator: 2..5:each>
```

We can convert this enumerator to an array to see what values it will pass into its block:

```
enum.to_a              #=> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

As `n => 7` you may be wondering why this array ends at `5`. That's because there are no arrays containing three positive integers, of which at least one is a `6` or a `7`, whose elements sum to `7`.

The first value `enum` passes into the block, which is represented by the block variable `i`, is `2`. We will now compute a hash `g` that includes all arrays that sum to `n => 7` or less, have at most `k => 3` elements, *include one or more `2`'s and zero or more `1`'s*.  (That's a bit of a mouthful, but it's still not precise, as I will explain.)

```
enum2 = (1..[n/i,k].min).each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]})
  #=> (1..[7/2,3].min).each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]})
  #=> (1..3).each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]})
```

[Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) creates an initially-empty hash that is represented by the block variable `f`.  The default value of this hash is such that:

```
f[k] << o
```

is equivalent to

```
(f[k] |= []) << o
```

meaning that if `f` does not have a key `k`,

```
f[k] = []
```

is executed before

```
f[k] << o
```

is performed.

`enum2` will pass the following elements into its block:

```
enum2.to_a #=> => [[1, {}], [2, {}], [3, {}]]
```

(though the hash may not be empty when elements after the first are passed into the block).  The first element passed to the block is `[1, {}]`, represented by the block variables:

```
m => 1
f => Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}
```

`m => 1` means we will intially construct arrays that contain one (`i=`) `2`.

```
im = [i]*m #=> [2]*1 => [2]  
mxi = m*i  #=>   2*1 =>  2
```

As `(m == k) #=> (1 == 3) => false`, we next execute

```
f[mxi] << im if mxi + (k-m)*(i+1) <= n
  #=> f[2] << [2] if 2 + (3-1)*(1+1) <= 7
  #=> f[2] << [2] if 8 <= 7
```

This considers whether `[2]` should be added to `f[2]` *without adding any integers `j < i = 2`*. (We have yet to consider the combining of one `2` with integers less than `2` [i.e., `1`].)  As `8 <= 7`, we do not add `[2]` to `f[2]`. The reason is that, for this to be part of an array of length `k=3`, it would be of the form `[2,x,y]`, where `x > 2` and `y > 2`, so `2+x+y >= 2+3+3 = 8 > n = 7`.  Clear as mud?

Next,

```
enum3 = (1..[(i-1)*(k-m), n-mxi].min).each
  #=> = (1..[2,5].min).each
  #=> = (1..2).each
  #=> #<Enumerator: 1..2:each>
```

which passes the values

```
enum3.to_a #=> [1, 2]
```

into its block, represented by the block variable `j`, which is the key of the hash `h`.  What we will be doing here is combine one `2` (`m=1`) with arrays of elements containing integers up to `1` (i.e., just `1`) that sum to `j`, so the elements of the resulting array will sum to `m * i + j => 1 * 2 + j => 2 + j`.

The reason `enum3` does not pass values of `j` greater than `2` into its block is that `h[l]` is empty for `l > 2` (but its a little more complicated when `i > 2`).

For `j => 1`,

```
h[j]              #=> [[1]]
enum4 = h[j].each #=> #<Enumerator: [[1]]:each>
enum4.to_a        #=> [[1]]
a                 #=> [1]
```

so

```
f[mxi+j].concat([a+im]) if
  ((a.size==k-m && mxi+j==n) || (a.size<k-m && (mxi+j+(k-m-a.size)*(i+1))<=n))
  #=> f[2+1].concat([[1]+[2]) if ((1==2 && 2+1==7) || (1<=3-1 && (2+1+(1)*(3)<=7)) 
  #=> f[3].concat([1,2])      if ((false && false) || (1<=2   && (6<=7))
  #=> f[3] = [] << [[1,2]]    if (false            || (true   && true)
  #=> f[3] = [[1,2]]          if true
```

So the expression on the left is evaluated. Again, the conditional expressions are a little complex.  Consider first:

```
a.size==k-m && mxi+j==n
```

which is equivalent to:

```
([2] + f[j]).size == k && ([2] + f[j]).reduce(:+) == n
```

That is, include the array `[2] + f[j]` if it has `k` elements that sum to `n`.

The second condition considers whether the array the arrays `[2] + f[j]` with fewer than `k` elements can be "completed" with integers `l > i = 2` and have a sum of `n` or less.

Now, `f #=> {3=>[[1, 2]]}`.

We now increment `j` to `2` and consider arrays `[2] + h[2]`, whose elements will total `4`.

For `j => 2`,

```
h[j]              #=> [[1, 1]]
enum4 = h[j].each #=> #<Enumerator: [[1, 1]]:each>
enum4.to_a        #=> [[1, 1]]
a                 #=> [1, 1]

f[mxi+j].concat([a+im]) if
  ((a.size==k-m && mxi+j==n) || (a.size<k-m && (mxi+j+(k-m-a.size)*(i+1)<=n))
  #=> f[4].concat([1, 1, 2]) if ((2==(3-1) && 2+2 == 7) || (2+2+(3-1-2)*(3)<=7))
  #=> f[4].concat([1, 1, 2]) if (true      && false)    || (false && true))
  #=> f[4].concat([1, 1, 2]) if false
```

so this operation is not performed (since `[1,1,2].size => 3 = k` and `[1,1,2].reduce(:+) => 4 < 7 = n`.

We now increment `m` to `2`, meaning that we will construct arrays having two (`i`=) `2`'s.  After doing so, we see that:

```
f={3=>[[1, 2]], 4=>[[2, 2]]}
```

and no other arrays are added when `m => 3`, so we have:

```
g #=> {3=>[[1, 2]], 4=>[[2, 2]]}
```

The statement

```
g.update({ n=>[i]*k }) if i*k == n
  #=> g.update({ 7=>[2,2,2] }) if 6 == 7
```

adds the element `7=>[2,2,2]` to the hash `g` if the sum of its elements equals `n`, which it does not.

We now fold `g` into `h`, using [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka Hash#merge!):

```
h.update(g) { |k,ov,nv| ov+nv }
  #=> {}.update({3=>[[1, 2]], 4=>[[2, 2]]} { |k,ov,nv| ov+nv }
  #=> {1=>[[1]], 2=>[[1, 1]], 3=>[[1, 2]], 4=>[[2, 2]]}
```

Now `h` contains all the arrays (values) whose keys are the array totals, comprised of the integers `1` and `2`, which have at most `3` elements and sum to at most `7`, excluding those arrays with fewer than `3` elements which cannot sum to `7` when integers greater than two are added.

The operations performed are as follows:

```
 i    m    j         f

 h #=> { 1=>[[1]], 2=>[[1,1]] } 

 2    1    1   {3=>[[1, 2]]}
 2    1    2   {3=>[[1, 2]]}
 2    2    1   {3=>[[1, 2]], 4=>[[2, 2]]}
                                {3=>[[1, 2]], 4=>[[2, 2]]}
 3    1    1   {}
 3    1    2   {}
 3    1    3   {}
 3    1    4   {7=>[[2, 2, 3]]}
 3    2    1   {7=>[[2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3]]}

 g before g.update: {7=>[[2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3]]}
 g after  g.update: {7=>[[2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3]]}

 h after h.update(g): {1=>[[1]],
                       2=>[[1, 1]],
                       3=>[[1, 2]],
                       4=>[[2, 2]],
                       7=>[[2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3]]}
 4   1     1   {}
 4   1     2   {}
 4   1     3   {7=>[[1, 2, 4]]}

 g before g.update: {7=>[[1, 2, 4]]}
 g after  g.update: {7=>[[1, 2, 4]]}

 h after h.update(g): {1=>[[1]],
                       2=>[[1, 1]],
                       3=>[[1, 2]],
                       4=>[[2, 2]],
                       7=>[[2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3], [1, 2, 4]]}
 5   1  1   {}
 5   1  2   {7=>[[1, 1, 5]]}

 g before g.update: {7=>[[1, 1, 5]]}
 g after  g.update: {7=>[[1, 1, 5]]}

 h after h.update(g): {1=>[[1]],
                       2=>[[1, 1]],
                       3=>[[1, 2]],
                       4=>[[2, 2]],
                       7=>[[2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 1, 5]]}
```

And lastly,

```
h[n].select { |a| a.size == k }
  #=> h[7].select { |a| a.size == 3 }
  #=> [[2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 1, 5]]
```

Comment: I have used it. Try to use it as combos(100,4) or combos(100,5). It would take a lot of response time. So to handle that case, i write my own code and also find response time faster than the  Array#repeated_combination.

Comment: I reported `combos(4,100)`, but yes, I agree with you.  I will have something better in awhile (that's the '..to be continued' reference).

Comment: Thanks Cary. This is really a good answer with good response time.

Comment: I'm glad to be of help, Tarun.  I'll elaborate the explanation later today.

Comment: It would be a great learning and help for me. Thanks sir. I appreciate your knowledge and efforts.

Comment: I completed the explanation.  I hope it is clear.  The algorithm is somewhat complex, so the explanation was a bit of a challenge, and is rather lengthy.

Comment: You have a bug - `combos(10, 5)` does not contain `[2,2,2,2,2]`

Comment: @Uri, thanks for pointing out the problem.  I'll fix the code after confirming the problem.  Because of the complexity of my code (and the fact that I had neither the time nor inclination to do thorough testing), I was concerned that I might not have eradicated all the bugs.  If the downvote was yours, you certainly are a stern taskmaster! Regardless, I look forward to reading your solution later today.

Comment: @Uri, I fixed the bug (formerly I had `n=>[i]*k` in the line `g.update({ n=>[[i]*k] }) if i*k == n`).  I can't be certain that it is now bug-free, but `u_combos(n,k).sort == c_combos(n,k)` does not evaluate `false` for any of several `n,k` combinations I tried.

Answer (score 1):

@Cary's answer is very in-depth and impressive, but it appears to me that there is a much more naive solution, which proved to be much more efficient as well - good old recursion:

```
def combos(n,k)
  if k == 1
    return [n]
  end
  (1..n-1).flat_map do |i|
    combos(n-i,k-1).map { |r| [i, *r].sort }
  end.uniq
end
```

This solution simply reduces the problem each level by taking decreasing the target sum by each number between 1 and the previous target sum, while reducing `k` by one. Now make sure you don't have duplicates (by `sort` and `uniq`) - and you have your answer...

This is great for `k < 5`, and is much faster than Cary's solution, but as `k` gets larger, I found that it makes much too many iterations, `sort` and `uniq` took a very big toll on the calculation.

So I made sure that won't be needed, by making sure I get only sorted answers - each recursion should check only numbers larger than those already used:

```
def combos(n,k,min = 1)
  if n < k || n < min
    return []
  end
  if k == 1
    return [n]
  end
  (min..n-1).flat_map do |i|
    combos(n-i,k-1, i).map { |r| [i, *r] }
  end
end
```

This solution is on par with Cary's on `combos(100, 7)`:

```
              user     system      total        real
My Solution   2.570000   0.010000   2.580000 (  2.695615)
Cary's        2.590000   0.000000   2.590000 (  2.609374)
```

But we can do better: caching! This recursion does many calculations again and again, so caching stuff we already did will save us a lot of work when dealing with long sums:

```
def combos(n,k,min = 1, cache = {})
  if n < k || n < min
    return []
  end
  cache[[n,k,min]] ||= begin
    if k == 1
      return [n]
    end
    (min..n-1).flat_map do |i|
      combos(n-i,k-1, i, cache).map { |r| [i, *r] }
    end
  end
end
```

This solution is mighty fast and passes Cary's solution for large `n` by light-years:

```
Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report('Uri') { combos(1000, 3) }
  bm.report('Cary') { combos_cary(1000, 3) }
end

       user     system      total        real
Uri   0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (  0.214080)
Cary  7.210000   0.000000   7.210000 (  7.220085)
```

And is on par with `k` as high as 9, and I believe it is still less complicated than his solution.

Comment: This is very impressive, @Uri.

Comment: @Uri, this is really great

Answer (score 0):

You want the number of [integer partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of `n` into exactly `k` summands. There is a (computationally) somewhat ugly recurrence for that number.

The idea is this: let `P(n,k)` be the number of ways to partition `n` into `k` nonzero summands; then `P(n,k) = P(n-1,k-1) + P(n-k,k)`. Proof: every partition either contains a `1` or it doesn't contain a 1 as one of the summands. The first case `P(n-1,k-1)` calculates the number of cases where there is a `1` in the sum; take that `1` away from the sum and partition the remaining `n-1` into the now available `k-1` summands. The second case `P(n-k,k)` considers the case where every summand is strictly greater than `1`; to do that, reduce all of the `k` summands by `1` and recurse from there. Obviously, `P(n,1) = 1` for all `n > 0`.

[Here's a link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240427/partitions-of-an-integer-into-k-parts) that mentions that probably, no closed form is known for general `k`.

Comment: If someone knows a more commonplace word for "summand", please let me know.

Comment: The 'Here's code' link you gave is to produce all partitions with any number of summands.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That was wrong, thanks for pointing it out. Will look for a link to code that does what we want.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Terms is a little more general an expression than I intended. I was aiming for a commonly used expression for "additive part of a term", for which dictionaries give me the options "summand" and "addend". Is either of those commonly used?

Comment: I have an idea for how to do it efficiently, and will put some time into it this evening.  btw, I love all your tunes, but especially the  [cello suite #1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHIQ838103U). Oh, wait. "G"?

Comment: Term connotes "additive part" for me. The components of a product are factors; the components of a sum are terms; the whole is an expression.